# Scrape memorystore redis metrics to prometheus

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, redis-cluster, google-cloud-memorystore

Can someone help me in scraping memory store redis metrics to prometheus. 
I installed a redis-exporter and enabled below values in servicemonitor.

```
  endpoints:
  - interval: 30s
    path: /metrics
    scrapeTimeout: 10s
    targetPort: 6379
```

Question: I don't see any option with metrics, while creating memorystore in gcp. How we can scrape and monitor redis health and queues.

Answer (score -1):

In the [Public documentation of Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/monitoring-instances) is described the process to monitor your Redis instance.

The process described is going to Monitoring > Metrics Explorer > Select redis_instance as the resource type and redis/server/uptime as the metric, or to select any of the described metrics in the documentation.

I understand that Prometheus is best suited to monitor Kubernetes. I can’t find any [official documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/) describing how to set it with Memorystore.